# Understanding how to test a class using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The main thing I am looking to achieve from this question is understanding. With some assistance I have been looking at refactoring my controller code into more manageable modules/classes so that I can test them effectively. I have an example here that I would like to work on, my question is how would I test the class `Sale`:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    payment = BraintreeTransaction::VerifyPayment.new(params, @user_id, @transaction_total)
    payment.run(params)

  if payment.success?
    redirect_to thank_you_path
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = payment.error
    flash.keep
    redirect_to new_transaction_path
  end
end

module BraintreeTransaction
  class VerifyPayment
    def initialize(params, user_id, total)
      @transaction_total = total
      @user_id = user_id
      @params = params
      @error_message = nil
   end

  def run(params)
    @result = BraintreeTransaction::Sale.new.braintree_hash(params, @transaction_total)
    if @result.success?
      @cart_items = CartItem.where(user_id: @user_id).where.not(image_id: nil)
     @cart_items.destroy_all
     create_real_user
     update_completed_transaction
     guest_user.destroy
     @success = true
  else
    update_transaction
    @error_message = BraintreeErrors::Errors.new.error_message(@result)
  end
end

  def success?
    @success
  end

  def error
    @error_message
  end
end 

module BraintreeTransaction
  class Sale
    def braintree_hash(params, total)
      Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        amount: total,
        payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce],
        device_data: params[:device_data],
        customer: {
          first_name: params[:first_name],
          last_name: params[:last_name],
          email: params[:email],
          phone: params[:phone]
        },
        billing: {
          first_name: params[:first_name],
          last_name: params[:last_name],
          company: params[:company],
          street_address: params[:street_address],
          locality: params[:locality],
       region: params[:region],
         postal_code: params[:postal_code]
       },
       shipping: {
        first_name: params[:shipping_first_name].presence || params[:first_name].presence,
      last_name: params[:shipping_last_name].presence || params[:last_name].presence,
        company: params[:shipping_company].presence || params[:company].presence,
      street_address: params[:shipping_street_address].presence || params[:street_address].presence,
         locality: params[:shipping_locality].presence || params[:locality].presence,
      region: params[:shipping_region].presence || params[:region].presence,
      postal_code: params[:shipping_postal_code].presence || params[:postal_code].presence
    },
    options: {
      submit_for_settlement: true,
      store_in_vault_on_success: true
    }
  )
  end
 end
end
```

I don't know if I am looking at this wrong but this piece of code here `BraintreeTransaction::Sale.new.braintree_hash` is what I want to test and I want to ensure that when called the class receives a hash ?

### Update

So far I have come up with this (though I am not 100% confident it is the correct approach ?)

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe BraintreeTransaction::Sale do
 @transaction_total = 100
 let(:params) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:braintree_transaction, amount: @transaction_total) }
 it 'recieves a hash when creating a payment' do
  expect_any_instance_of(BraintreeTransaction::Sale).to receive(:braintree_hash).with(params, @transaction_total).and_return(true)
 end
end
```

I get an error returned which I don't understand

```
Failure/Error: DEFAULT_FAILURE_NOTIFIER = lambda { |failure, _opts| raise failure }
Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: braintree_hash
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not be spot on but I would answer the way I would have tackled the issue. There are three ways you can write a test that hits the code you want to test.

- Write a unit test for `braintree_hash` for `BraintreeTransaction::Sale` object
- Write a controller unit method for `create` method in `TransactionsController` controller
- write an integration test for route for `create` method in `TransactionsController`.

These are the ways you can start exploring.

Comment: what would help me and be useful as an answer would be to see examples of how you would go about each test if you can please

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here. All the suggestions for refactoring your code (from your other question [Writing valuable controller tests - Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440167/writing-valuable-controller-tests-rspec)) apply here. I can make further suggestions on this code, if helpful.

In your test, I believe your problem is that you never actually call `BraintreeTransaction.new.braintree_hash(params)` (which should be called immediately following your `expect_any_instance_of` declaration). And so no instances ever receive the message(s).